# Kinetic JS 5.1 .getContext()

Tags: kineticjs

I just updated Kinetic JS from 4.3.3 to 5.1, used the following to draw a circle, centered at two lines crossing:

```
    circle1.setDrawHitFunc(function (canvas) {
        var context1 = canvas.getContext();
        var centerX1 = blueLine1.getPosition().x;
        centerY1 = greenLine1.getPosition().y;
        context1.beginPath();
        context1.arc(centerX1, centerY1, this.getRadius(), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context1.closePath();
        canvas.fillStroke(this);
        currentX = canvas.width / 2;
        currentY = canvas.height / 2;
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'
```

I also get an error using stage1.getDragLayer().afterDraw as 
in my old example http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/cgF8y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of KineticJS has changed a great deal since V4.3.3.

Here's the new syntax for setting the hit function:

(Note that you're now given a context instead of a canvas as a parameter)

```
myShape.hitFunc( function(context){ ... } );
```

**[ Addition to answer to refactor your code to work in KineticJS V5.1 ]**

A working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2QG5W/

[image][image]

KineticJS now has a `dragmove` event which lets you respond every time your greenLine or blueLine is dragged.

This means you can:

- Listen for `dragmove` on the green line and automatically reposition the circle vertically.
- Listen for `dragmove` on the blue line and automatically reposition the circle horizontally.

This is much simpler than the way it had to be done in version4!

Here's how:

```
// reposition the circle vertically 
// every time the green line is dragged vertically

GreenLine1.on('dragmove',function(){
    circle1.y(GreenLine1.y()+GreenLine1.points()[1]);
    layer.draw();
});


// reposition the circle horizontally 
// every time the blue line is dragged horizontally

BlueLine1.on('dragmove',function(){
    circle1.x(BlueLine1.x()+BlueLine1.points()[0]);
    layer.draw();
});
```

**One other thing**

You can set a `dragBoundFunc` to keep the user from dragging your green line horizontally and keep the user from dragging your blue line vertically.

Here's how:

```
// save the X position of the green line

GreenLine1.fixedX=GreenLine1.x();

// let the user drag the green line vertically
// but not horizontally

GreenLine1.dragBoundFunc(function(pos){
    pos.x=GreenLine1.fixedX;
    return(pos);
});



// save the X position of the green line

BlueLine1.fixedY=BlueLine1.y();

// let the user drag the blue line horizontally
// but not vertically

BlueLine1.dragBoundFunc(function(pos){
    pos.y=BlueLine1.fixedY;
    return(pos);
});
```

Comment: I have added to my answer showing your 4.3 code refactored to work well with version 5.1.  Good luck with your project!